# Crazy display issue with website pages. Items vanish ...but only sometimes. IE8

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

Here is the situation. I am using IE8 to view my website, both off and online. The website is mostly PHP, MySql, a separate CSS sylesheet and of course all the HTML needed in between.

The problem is that sometimes, when viewing both my offline development version files and the uploaded online version on the live website itself - intermittantly, some "pieces" will not display. These are sometimes some of the graphics or some of the text.

If the page is long enough in length (off the screen) I can wiggle the vertical scrollbar and the stuff will pop back into view. Sometimes I can get all items back by refreshing the browser too. Again, sometimes there simply is no problem at all and everything displays just fine. It's maddening.

I searched and couldn't find a specific answer to this. I also didn't include any code because I don't have a clue as to what part may be causing this erratic behaviour. If anyone has had the same problem and managed to resolve it - please share. I'd be greatful.

Although I have not included code (proprietary reasons) the work in progress can be viewed at www.auxcash.com - using w3c validation services both CSS and HTML checks out except for minor missing "alt"s for a couple of images. Also, I think the hasLayout no longer applies to IE8 in reading [articles](http://haslayout.net/haslayout).

Comment: I've had this before. I can't remember what caused it. Have you set a doctype and that kind of thing? Does all the HTML & CSS validate?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely this issue is cause by IE's propery [hasLayout](http://haslayout.net/haslayout).
Install [IE developer Toolba](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535)r and try to inspect the elements in your code.

This property ( which , btw, is not css property and cannot be set directly ) is the one causing most of IE rendering bugs.

P.S. this all is just a guess , because you didn't provide any testcase or live page to look at.

Comment: +1 and you might want to try the "magic hack" `html * {zoom: 1}` but it will probably break more than it repairs because some elements behave better when not having layout...